# Обновление списка listview после удаления символов из строки поиска

Tags: java, android

Добавил несколько пунктов listview из массива строк и пришпандорил простенький поиск по элементам. При этом при каждом новом символе список обновляется. Это все круто, но хотелось, чтобы при удалении символов, список также обновлялся и соответственно плавно снова увеличивался. Но этого почему-то не происходит.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.arseny.songbook;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] items;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
        initList();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    initList();
                } else {
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id){
            case R.id.action_settings :
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, com.example.arseny.songbook.Activity_Three.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            String textToSearch1 = textToSearch.toLowerCase();

            if(!item.toLowerCase().contains(textToSearch1)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void initList() {
        items = new String[]{"...", "...", "..."};
        listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, com.example.arseny.songbook.Activity_Two.class);
                intent.putExtra("names", itemValue);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Если нужны какие то анимации и плавность, стоит использовать RecyclerView, DiffUtils и вот это вот все

Comment: А как их добавить? Помогите пожалуйста не очень понял! Можете пример скинуть если не сложно?

Answer (score 2):

Можно по разному. Например так:

1. Храните 2 списка элементов полный и тот, который отображаете.
2. При поиске очищайте 2 список и наполняйте его согласно алгоритму соответствия
3. Для отображения в адаптере используйте 2 список.

Так у вас будет нужное вам поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы ищете событие при котором обновлять список то попробуйте onTextChanged:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    if (s.length() > 0)
            { //do your work here }
    }

}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
```